# Android app development -- how to change Firestore databases

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to prepare **production** and **development** databases for our current project. After creating the new firestore database, I created a signed apk and got a `.keystore` file from which I could generate a `SHA-1` fingerprint. I pasted the fingerprint at the **development** database where I also added the app. I then downloaded the `google-services.json` file into my android studio file and rebuilt the project. The result was that the app is still using the old database.

I'm certain I didn't use the same fingerprint on two databases, otherwise it would not have worked on authentication. However, I was under the assumption that changing the `google-services.json` file would allow me to change between databases. Am I doing anything wrong?

**Edit:** The rough structure of the services file is like so:

```
`{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "5**********6",
    "project_id": "f**********-project-dev",
    "storage_bucket": "f**********-project-dev.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:5**********6:android:5********************d",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.**********.some_project"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "5**********6-5******************************4.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.**********.some_project",
            "certificate_hash": "6**************************************5"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "5**********6-e******************************6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "***************************************"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "5**********6-1******************************h.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}`
```

If, perhaps, anyone could also share a sample format of a `google-services.json` file for multiple databases configured in a single app (if that's possible to do), it would help me figure out potential problems in my file.

Comment: Can you share the `google-services.json` ?

Comment: Can you show the Android code of how you initialize the Firestore database and get a reference to the one you want to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue after a long time. Posting it here if it helps anyone.

I was granted owner access to the firebase database where I could see on [the firestore credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) that there was a duplicate generated api key for the same mobile app I'm using. I deleted the duplicate, removed the app from the development database on Firebase console, generated the fingerprint, added the mobile app to firebase with the fingerprint, and it worked.